# datepicker requires refresh on multiple pages

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, refresh

I have a datepicker form included on each page of a financial accounting web site. The date picker is designed to allow users to select a range of dates for the data that they want displayed.

Unfortunately, the only way to get the calendars to appear when the text field has focus, as a user navigates from page to page, is for a hard refresh (Ctrl-R). Not the optimum.

here's the form:

```
<li data-data-theme='b' >
<label for="from">From</label>  
<input type="text" id="from" name="from"/>
</li>

<li data-data-theme='d'>
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to"/>
</li>
```

And here's the jquery:

```
    $(function() {

        console.log("hello world 2");

        $( "#from" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            stepMonths: 3,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            showOptions: {direction: 'up'},
            showButtonPanel: true,
            yearRange: "2011:2019", 
            showAnim: "fold",
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#to" ).datepicker();
            }
        });
        $( "#to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            stepMonths: 3,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            showOptions: {direction: 'up'},
            showButtonPanel: true,
            yearRange: "2011:2019", 
            showAnim: "fold",
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#from" ).datepicker();
            }
        });
    });


}

$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log("hello world");


    $(function() {

        console.log("hello world 2");

        $( "#from" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            stepMonths: 3,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            showOptions: {direction: 'up'},
            showButtonPanel: true,
            yearRange: "2011:2019", 
            showAnim: "fold",
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            showOn: 'button', 
        buttonImage: 'images/datepicker_icon.png', 
        buttonImageOnly: true,

            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#to" ).datepicker();
            }
        });
        $( "#to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            stepMonths: 3,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            showOptions: {direction: 'up'},
            showButtonPanel: true,
            yearRange: "2011:2019", 
            showAnim: "fold",
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#from" ).datepicker();
            }
        });
    });



});
```

I have tried changing the form to include reference to a class: eg:

```
<li data-data-theme='b' >
<label for="from">From</label>  
<input class='datepicker' type="text" id="from" name="from"/>
</li>

<li data-data-theme='d'>
<label for="to">to</label>
<input class='datepicker' type="text" id="to" name="to"/>
</li>
```

and then referencing that in the jquery function thus:

```
   $(function() {

      console.log("hello world 2");

    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({

           ...

           onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
                }
    });
       });
```

but all to no avail.

So, here's the question: how do I have the datepicker calendar appear when a user navigates to a new page on the web site?

Comment: Do you mean: go to a page, click from/to but date picker does not appear. But you refresh the page, click from.to, datepicker is fine?

Answer (score 0):

would you like to open datepicker by default..when user comes to these pages. if yes you have to configure display inline property of datepicker see example [Example datepicker display inline](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline)

```
$(function() {
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({altField: '#date1'});
});
```